# Why do I see sp_OACreate, sp_OASetProperty in sp_WhoIsActive?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ole-automation

I've seen this happen a few times: sp_WhoIsActive shows various sp_OA% sprocs, with my user name, but I'm certainly not running them directly.  Does this reflect some kind of query rewrite process?  It seems to be correlated with queries across remote servers.

Comment: Is the remote server a linked server? Is it SQL Server or some other data source? Is it possible the sp_OA calls are happening there?

Comment: Good questions, I should have spelled that out.  The linked server is also MS SQL, 2K5 as it happens.  I'm just joining to a plain vanilla table on that remote server, there are no views, calculated columns, or TVFs involved.

Comment: And you're sure that query is the one that is causing sp_OA references? Have you run a server-side trace (which you could filter to that query text) to dig deeper?

Comment: I confirmed that a specific view created these odd references.  I have the advantage that all normal traffic runs through other user accounts, so anything with my AD user name is generally something I'm running ad-hoc in SQL Studio.

Comment: A view made a reference to `sp_OACreate`? I'd be interested to see the syntax for that. :-)

Comment: Well, to be exact the view includes a UDF which calls another UDF which uses `sp_OACreate` and friends.  The first UDF validates an e-mail address, and the second is a reg ex wrapper.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you search your system catalogs for stored procedures that might be calling them? In DBs where you see this:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME([object_id]), definition
   FROM sys.sql_modules
   WHERE definition LIKE '%sp[_]OA%';
```

To do this for all databases at once:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) 
   + 'SELECT ''' + name + ''', o.name, m.definition
   FROM ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.objects AS o
   INNER JOIN ' + QUOTENAME(name) + '.sys.sql_modules AS m
   ON o.[object_id] = m.[object_id]
   WHERE m.definition LIKE ''%sp[_]OA%'';'
FROM sys.databases;

EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
```

You might also check job steps.

```
SELECT j.name, s.step_name, command
   FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps AS s
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs AS j
   ON s.job_id = j.job_id
   WHERE s.command LIKE '%sp_OA%';
```

If you don't find anything there, you will want to run a server-side trace because it must be coming from ad hoc batches.

Comment: Your guess was spot-on!  My query includes a UDF which calls another UDF which uses several `sp_OA`% sprocs.  These sprocs are so unfamiliar, it didn't occur to me that I could be using them, but I didn't consider this obscure UDF.  Another reminder to always check the simple stuff first.  Thank you!